# JOptionPane and While Loop (user input addition)

Tags: loops, while-loop, joptionpane, addition

```
    package iCanDoIt;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Practice {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        String msg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(msg);
        String msg2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter another number");
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(msg2);
        int addition=num1+num2;

        String msg3=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is" + num1 + "+ " + num2 + " ? ");

        int answer=Integer.parseInt(msg3);

        while(num1+num2!=answer){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"try again");
            String answer2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("wrong. what is " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "?");
            int answer3=Integer.parseInt(answer2);

        if (num1+num2==answer3)

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"GREAT job");


        }
        System.exit(0);

        }


    }
```

I am a beginner at JAVA.

Scanner input seems pretty easy to understand but for some reason I am having a difficult time using JOptionPane.

Anyway, my problem is...Even after I get the answer correct, I keep getting "try again"

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never updating `answer`.

Change this

```
int answer3=Integer.parseInt(answer2);
if (num1+num2==answer3)
```

to this

```
answer=Integer.parseInt(answer2);
if (num1+num2==answer)
```

You could also get rid of the `if (num1+num2==answer)` check by moving your final message dialog outside the loop:

```
    int answer=Integer.parseInt(msg3);

    while(num1+num2!=answer){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"try again");
        String answer2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("wrong. what is " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "?");
        answer=Integer.parseInt(answer2);

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"GREAT job");
    System.exit(0);
```